# UI becomes unresponsive while trying to unzip

Tags: mouse, zip

I have been facing this issue for quite some time; Sometimes - I don't know if this is random or not, and it is not related to the archive size - when I try to unzip the file, the UI becomes completely unresponsive. It is possible to move the mouse cursor, but the pointer is changed to hand shape and it is not possible to click anywhere and the only thing I can do is to select Ctrl+Alt+F1 and run sudo reboot. If I try to unzip the same file by running unzip command from the terminal, the file is unzipped successfully.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Since you can reach a TTY, check your CPU load, memory usage, and the messages in your logs while the GUI is unresponsive. Try taking a 10-minute break and see if the GUI resumes without requiring a reboot. Test a 21.10 Live USB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, and see if you can reproduce the behavior in the latest release of Ubuntu.